Не работает firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler
Настроил уведомления Firebase они приходят и в открытом и закрытом.
Вот пример кода
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('ok');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  AppMetrica.runZoneGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await AppMetrica.activate(config.appMetricaConfig);
    HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
    Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
    ...
    ...
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    runApp(AppContainer());
   });
 }

Но код внутри firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler не хочет выполняться.
Тестирую это на IOS но в андройде проблема повторяется.
Все разрешения на уведомления даны.
Нужно чтобы если уведомление приходило в свёрнутом или закрытом приложении выполнялся определённый код. К примеру отправка пост запроса.
